# date function passing undefined object

Tags: javascript

[image]

```
function addDays(date, days) {

          var result = new Date(date);
          console.log("initialdate"+result);
          result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
          result=result.toLocaleDateString();
          result = result.split(' ')[0];
          return result;
     }
```

I am trying to add days to a date, however when I convert a date into object I get an error as Invalid date

This is the HTML code.

```
<div class="form-line"> <label for="date">Date</label> <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="edit_date" placeholder="Enter Date" required="true" value>
```

Comment: Please show an example of what you're passing in as `date` and `days` to the function, and what you expect the output to be. Note that images of code and debugging tools are generally not well received as it is impossible to copy and paste the values/code into our own IDEs to replicate the error.

Comment: Can you try mm/dd/yyyy format once

Comment: console.log(new Date("23/05/2019")) is invalid due to date format

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is your input format. For parsing to work the format will need to be either `YYYY/MM/DD` or `MM/DD/YYYY`.

```js
function addDays(date, days) {

          var result = new Date(date);
          console.log("initialdate: "+result);
          result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
          result=result.toLocaleDateString();
          result = result.split(' ')[0];
          console.log("return: "+result);
          return result;
     }
     
     addDays("05/25/2019", 5);
     addDays("2019/05/24", 5);
```

Comment: I am taking the date as an input from the user. Differnt browsers are having different date format, how should i resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of changing date in 'DD/MM/YYYY' to valid ISO 8601 format for Date constructor

1. format date to new Date(YYYY, MM, DD) by splitting date in format -DD/MM/YYYY
2. Month value starts from 0 for Jan , decrease by 1 for getting valid month
3. Add days using setDate

```js
function addDays(date, days) {
          let fomarttedDate = date.split("/")
          var result = new Date(fomarttedDate[2], fomarttedDate[1] -1, fomarttedDate[0]);
          result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
          result=result.toLocaleDateString();
          result = result.split(' ')[0];
          return result;
     }

console.log(addDays("23/05/2019", 2))
```

Please refer this link for more details on datestring valid formats
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zQvpaa